# Content moderator，Results of the false positives how to solve?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Content Moderator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/content-moderator/

My picture is taken as a porn picture. How to fix this error?

[False Positives Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPdxQ.jpg)

add:

**There is no error in the code,I use the official interface(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/try-image-api)**

**Request Body**

- IsImageAdultClassified:True
- IsImageRacyClassified:True

Comment: I am not in to MS cognitive services. But is there any other details you can share with us. I mean SO is about code issues. Do you have any code that result it, or any error logs that will help others to help you?

Comment: Already updated

Comment: Maybe because it's car porn?

Comment: Pornography should not be human?

Comment: Bad, bad joke. Sorry, couldn't resist... :p Have a look at the racyScore, so you can see actually how racy it thinks it is. You might want to implement a threshold. For instance keep everything under 0.70, and flag the rest as (possibly) adult.

Comment: In addition to setting a threshold based on racyScore, is there any way to manually change his results?

Comment: Take a look at the different scenarios: human, automated and hybrid moderation. There's even a tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/quick-start

Comment: yes,I know this.we have a review system background,So did not use Microsoft's review background.Whether there is an api to change the status of the picture

Answer (score 0):

Elchan,

I tried the image and I get the following response. **The image was not tagged as racy or adult.**

Make sure you select the correct region (same as your API key region) from this page:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66c

My request field (text entry) looks like this: (this is your image)

```
{
  "DataRepresentation":"URL",
  "Value":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPdxQ.jpg"
}
```

The response looked like this:

```
{
  "AdultClassificationScore": 0.035331539809703827,
  "IsImageAdultClassified": false,
  "RacyClassificationScore": 0.043926537036895752,
  "IsImageRacyClassified": false,
  "AdvancedInfo": [{
    "Key": "ImageDownloadTimeInMs",
    "Value": "203"
  }, {
    "Key": "ImageSizeInBytes",
    "Value": "9071"
  }],
  "Result": false,
  "Status": {
    "Code": 3000,
    "Description": "OK",
    "Exception": null
  },
  "TrackingId": "WE_a605a7bfeaca465eb2d8942389f9c86c_ContentModerator.Preview_24006777-6c57-4818-8c2e-146bcb24d3dc"
}
```

Having said that, you may find false positives or false negatives occurring when you use any machine-learning based API so it's quite possible that you may not get the correct results for other images. In that case, check the confidence scores and figure out a matching threshold that you use to block or pass through the images. (and yes, please send us the image so we can improve the models!)

In addition to auto-pass or auto-reject based on confidence scores, check out the [human review tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/review-tool-user-guide/human-in-the-loop) and [Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/try-review-api-job) and [Review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/try-review-api-review) API of Content Moderator if you have a human moderation team that can further review and change labels assigned by the Content Moderator API.

Let me know if you still have trouble. Please submit your questions via https://cognitive.uservoice.com/.

Comment: (and yes, please send us the image so we can improve the models!)  
**What way should I give back to you? email or api or ?**